# How to solve conflict errors when update mysql-server with yum

Tags: mysql, linux, centos, rpm, yum

I am trying to upgrade from version 5.5 to 5.6 of mysql on my server.
(I am not system administration)

I have run
`yum install https://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql80-community-release-el6-1.noarch.rpm`

After I have edited the file: `/etc/yum.repos.d/mysql-community.repo` putting the option enabled = 1 in version 5.6

```
# Enable to use MySQL 5.6
[mysql56-community]
name=MySQL 5.6 Community Server
baseurl=http://repo.mysql.com/yum/mysql-5.6-community/el/6/$basearch/
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-mysql
```

Below I have run sudo `yum update mysql-server`
I got the multiple conflicts:

```
Loaded plugins: copr, priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
amzn-main                                                                                                                                                                               | 2.1 kB  00:00:00
amzn-updates                                                                                                                                                                            | 3.8 kB  00:00:00
as-repo-amzn2                                                                                                                                                                           | 2.9 kB  00:00:00
copr:copr.fedorainfracloud.org:dsommers:openvpn-release                                                                                                                                 | 3.3 kB  00:00:00
copr:copr.fedorainfracloud.org:dsommers:openvpn3                                                                                                                                        | 3.3 kB  00:00:00
epel/x86_64/metalink                                                                                                                                                                    | 4.5 kB  00:00:00
mysql-connectors-community                                                                                                                                                              | 2.6 kB  00:00:00
mysql-tools-community                                                                                                                                                                   | 2.6 kB  00:00:00
mysql56-community                                                                                                                                                                       | 2.6 kB  00:00:00
1121 packages excluded due to repository priority protections
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package mysql-community-server.x86_64 0:5.6.51-2.el6 will be obsoleting
--> Processing Dependency: mysql-community-common(x86-64) = 5.6.51-2.el6 for package: mysql-community-server-5.6.51-2.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: mysql-community-client(x86-64) >= 5.6.10 for package: mysql-community-server-5.6.51-2.el6.x86_64
---> Package mysql-server.noarch 0:5.5-1.6.amzn1 will be obsoleted
--> Running transaction check
---> Package mysql-community-client.x86_64 0:5.6.51-2.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: mysql-community-libs(x86-64) >= 5.6.10 for package: mysql-community-client-5.6.51-2.el6.x86_64
---> Package mysql-community-common.x86_64 0:5.6.51-2.el6 will be installed
--> Running transaction check
---> Package mysql-community-libs.x86_64 0:5.6.51-2.el6 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

===============================================================================================================================================================================================================
 Package                                                  Arch                                     Version                                           Repository                                           Size
===============================================================================================================================================================================================================
Installing:
 mysql-community-server                                   x86_64                                   5.6.51-2.el6                                      mysql56-community                                    62 M
     replacing  mysql-server.noarch 5.5-1.6.amzn1
Installing for dependencies:
 mysql-community-client                                   x86_64                                   5.6.51-2.el6                                      mysql56-community                                    20 M
 mysql-community-common                                   x86_64                                   5.6.51-2.el6                                      mysql56-community                                   340 k
 mysql-community-libs                                     x86_64                                   5.6.51-2.el6                                      mysql56-community                                   2.2 M

Transaction Summary
===============================================================================================================================================================================================================
Install  1 Package (+3 Dependent packages)

Total size: 85 M
Is this ok [y/d/N]: y
Downloading packages:
Running transaction check
Running transaction test


Transaction check error:
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/README from install of mysql-community-common-5.6.51-2.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql55-server-5.5.62-1.23.amzn1.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/czech/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-community-common-5.6.51-2.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql55-server-5.5.62-1.23.amzn1.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/danish/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-community-common-5.6.51-2.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql55-server-5.5.62-1.23.amzn1.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/dutch/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-community-common-5.6.51-2.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql55-server-5.5.62-1.23.amzn1.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/english/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-community-common-5.6.51-2.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql55-server-5.5.62-1.23.amzn1.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/estonian/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-community-common-5.6.51-2.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql55-server-5.5.62-1.23.amzn1.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/french/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-community-common-5.6.51-2.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql55-server-5.5.62-1.23.amzn1.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/german/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-community-common-5.6.51-2.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql55-server-5.5.62-1.23.amzn1.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/greek/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-community-common-5.6.51-2.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql55-server-5.5.62-1.23.amzn1.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/hungarian/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-community-common-5.6.51-2.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql55-server-5.5.62-1.23.amzn1.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/italian/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-community-common-5.6.51-2.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql55-server-5.5.62-1.23.amzn1.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/japanese/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-community-common-5.6.51-2.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql55-server-5.5.62-1.23.amzn1.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/korean/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-community-common-5.6.51-2.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql55-server-5.5.62-1.23.amzn1.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/norwegian-ny/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-community-common-5.6.51-2.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql55-server-5.5.62-1.23.amzn1.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/norwegian/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-community-common-5.6.51-2.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql55-server-5.5.62-1.23.amzn1.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/polish/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-community-common-5.6.51-2.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql55-server-5.5.62-1.23.amzn1.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/portuguese/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-community-common-5.6.51-2.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql55-server-5.5.62-1.23.amzn1.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/romanian/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-community-common-5.6.51-2.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql55-server-5.5.62-1.23.amzn1.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/russian/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-community-common-5.6.51-2.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql55-server-5.5.62-1.23.amzn1.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/serbian/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-community-common-5.6.51-2.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql55-server-5.5.62-1.23.amzn1.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/slovak/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-community-common-5.6.51-2.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql55-server-5.5.62-1.23.amzn1.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/spanish/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-community-common-5.6.51-2.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql55-server-5.5.62-1.23.amzn1.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/swedish/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-community-common-5.6.51-2.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql55-server-5.5.62-1.23.amzn1.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/ukrainian/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-community-common-5.6.51-2.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql55-server-5.5.62-1.23.amzn1.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/Index.xml from install of mysql-community-common-5.6.51-2.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql55-server-5.5.62-1.23.amzn1.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/armscii8.xml from install of mysql-community-common-5.6.51-2.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql55-server-5.5.62-1.23.amzn1.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/ascii.xml from install of mysql-community-common-5.6.51-2.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql55-server-5.5.62-1.23.amzn1.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/cp1250.xml from install of mysql-community-common-5.6.51-2.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql55-server-5.5.62-1.23.amzn1.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/cp1251.xml from install of mysql-community-common-5.6.51-2.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql55-server-5.5.62-1.23.amzn1.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/cp1256.xml from install of mysql-community-common-5.6.51-2.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql55-server-5.5.62-1.23.amzn1.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/cp1257.xml from install of mysql-community-common-5.6.51-2.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql55-server-5.5.62-1.23.amzn1.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/cp850.xml from install of mysql-community-common-5.6.51-2.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql55-server-5.5.62-1.23.amzn1.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/cp852.xml from install of mysql-community-common-5.6.51-2.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql55-server-5.5.62-1.23.amzn1.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/cp866.xml from install of mysql-community-common-5.6.51-2.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql55-server-5.5.62-1.23.amzn1.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/dec8.xml from install of mysql-community-common-5.6.51-2.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql55-server-5.5.62-1.23.amzn1.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/geostd8.xml from install of mysql-community-common-5.6.51-2.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql55-server-5.5.62-1.23.amzn1.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/greek.xml from install of mysql-community-common-5.6.51-2.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql55-server-5.5.62-1.23.amzn1.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/hebrew.xml from install of mysql-community-common-5.6.51-2.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql55-server-5.5.62-1.23.amzn1.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/hp8.xml from install of mysql-community-common-5.6.51-2.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql55-server-5.5.62-1.23.amzn1.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/keybcs2.xml from install of mysql-community-common-5.6.51-2.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql55-server-5.5.62-1.23.amzn1.x86_64
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I resolve these conflicts to perform the upgrade?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to update a Amazon release of MySql (mysql55-server-5.5.62-1.23.amzn1.x86_64) to a Community release.

To do it this was you need to remove (yum erase) the amazon package first.

a guide for this has been produced - follow it loosely though for your own environment.

https://jinyuwang.weebly.com/for-mysql/how-to-upgrade-mysql-database-from-55-to-56-on-aws-ec2